# ¿Como conectarse a una Api con Laravel usando un parametro?

Tags: laravel, api

Hola estoy intentando conectarme a una APi con Laravel y me dieron un parametro para hacerlo.

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://factory.twonapp.com',
    'tiemout' =>'2.0',
]);

$res = $client->request('GET', 'info', [
    'Authorization' => ['codigo' ,'34576-9']
]);
```

Me dieron el parámetro código y el numero de ese código como formato xxxxx-x a mi libre elección.

He buscado en varios sitios y no logro encontrar la solución, el error que recibo es el siguiente:

> Server error: `GET https://factory.twonapp.com/info` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
>
> ## Internal Server Error

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Te esta devolviendo un error en el servidor, bien porque la aplicación esta fallando, o porque algo que estas haciendo produce esa respuesta.

Comment: el api debe estar fallando o la url esta mal, si colocas esa url en el navegador via post no hay response, quiere decir que no sirve